# MS-SQl Server 2012 for ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

is therer a way to install MS-SQL server 2012 on ubuntu 14.04 or
something similar to it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Server 2016 will eventually be released **for** Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/sql-server-on-linux.aspx). There'll be a preview at some point and then they'll roll it into the main version. This was only just announced a few days ago. Even once this is out, it will rely on you having a license for the 2016+, and your code being compatible with SQL Server 2016.

I've no idea when that'll release either. Until that's a real thing, your only real options are:

- Pick another database tech (MySQL, Postgres, etc). If you have a tightly coupled system running raw SQL commands, chances are this will require some additional development time.
- Virtualise a copy of Windows within Ubuntu and install SQL Server on that. Of course this comes with all the negatives of running Windows in the first place.

Other Windows applications can sometimes be run through intermediate libraries like Wine but that likely won't be an option for SQL Server because it has [too many server dependencies](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11312) that just aren't implemented in Wine. You'll need a real copy of Windows to run a real copy of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can install SQL Server on GNU/linux, but for now, only for Red Hat and Ubuntu and is still on Beta.

The following links tell you

> How to install SQL Server in Ubuntu and Red Hat

[Install SQL Server on Red Hat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-red-hat)

[Install SQL Server on Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu)

I installed that on a Linux Mint 18 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04, and have no problems yet. But consider the fact that is a BETA release, you must not use it for production.

Comment: Your answer doesn't reference OP's desire for 2012 server version or address the fact OP is running Ubuntu 14.04.